# canDeactivate in angular triggers on the initial load itself

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular, it's about 'canActivate' and 'canDeactivate'

As per my understanding, **canActivate** will trigger in the initial load and **canDeactivate** at the time of leaving the page.

here is the `routes.ts` structure

```
{
    path: 'pathA',
    component: PathAComponent,
    canDeactivate: [pathAExitGuard],
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: PAGE_NAME_STEPS[0],
            pathMatch: 'full',
            data: { pageName: 'Redirect' }
        },
        {
            path: PAGE_NAME_STEPS[0],
            component: StepComponent,
            canActivate: [pathAEnterGuard],
            data: { pageName: 'Step 1', service: SERVICE_ANALYTICS.PATHASERVICE },
        },
        {
            path: PAGE_NAME_STEPS[1],
            component: StepComponent,
            canActivate: [pathAEnterGuard],
            data: { pageName: 'Step 2', service: SERVICE_ANALYTICS.PATHASERVICE },
        }
    ],
}
```

here, both 'canActivate' and 'canDeactivate' trigger happens at the initial load (in the following order)
1)pathAEnterGuard
2)all component loading process
3)pathAExitGuard -- (without any event this gets triggered)

note: this is not happening in all time, occurs randomly.

I just wanted to know, which are the possible cases could make this happen?
I was searching for this whole day, in all I can only find "any click event or redirect event can cause this".

please give your suggestions on this